# GitlabCI and pipeline for a new branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

By default, Gitlab CI starts the pipeline when a new branch is created (based on an existing one, not even the main one). I don't understand how to turn this off? It should not run the pipeline and jobs when creating a new branch. Only when pushing into branches and open MR.

I have this now, but it doesn't work.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [`CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) which will be `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` when creating a new branch. Something like:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    # uncomment if you want tag pipelines 
    # - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
```

---

Alternatively, if you are pushing a new branch from the CLI, you can use a git [push option](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html) to skip the pipeline:

```bash
git push -o ci.skip
```